# NoClassDefFoundError when we execute a Java Web application within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I have a problem to submit because I'm pretty sure it exist a simple solution.

Precisions:

- I am a system administrator
- I publish this message because I tried to help my colleagues developers without success for the moment

We have a homemade shared library we will call "myLibrary": it is a Java library (a JAR when builded) we share between many of standalone applications (not modular applications).

This library provides, for example, a homemade abstract class to connect to MongoDB.
In its pom.xml:

- we have many dependencies
- one of these dependencies is mongodb-driver-sync:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

One of our application is a Java web server:

- we will call it "myApplication"
- in production we deploy the application within a Tomcat server

In the pom.xml of myApplication:

- we have many dependencies explicitely declared
- we have a dependency on "myLibrary" explicitely declared

When we build the WAR (with Eclipse thanks to the 'Maven Build' feature and/or through our CI/CD pipeline), we got a WAR which contain:

- all the dependencies explicitely declared
- the library myLibrary explicitely declared
- and implicitely we got the dependencies of myLibrary: thefore, in WEB-INF/lib, we have the JAR files for mongodb-driver-sync

At this level, it works perfectly.

But we have a problem when we try to execute this application directly in Eclipse (live development session/debug).

In this context, we got an error NoClassDefFoundError related to MongoDB.
We analysed a lot and the result is this one:

- when we execute the application in Eclipse, Eclipse deploys the application somewhere. We found the directory in which the application was deployed:

  - this directory contains a directory WEB-INF/lib

    - this WEB-INF/lib directory contains only the dependencies declared explicitely in pom.xml of myApplication: the dependencies of myLibrary are not embedded
    - if we add manually the missing JAR (example: MongoDB driver): it works

We tested many things but nothing seems to work except if we add explicitely the dependency in the pom.xml of myApplication:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

We would like to avoid this for many reasons.

Details about our environment:

- Eclipse: 2023-03
- JDK: 1.8
- Maven : 3.8.7

Is someone has an idea to suggest please?

Thank you very much.

We tried to execute mvn [...] eclipse:eclipse but it failed + we broke our project in Eclipse.

We tried to play with the feature "Java Build Path":

- adding "Maven Dependencies"
- removing "Maven Dependencies"
  -> it failed but maybe we missed something

We tried to play with the feature "Deployment Assembly":

- adding "myLibrary"
- removing "myLibrary"
  -> it failed but maybe we missed something

Comment: If you have a Maven-based applicaton don't modify "Java Build Path" manually in Eclipse: it must be managed by Maven.

Comment: "Eclipse deploys the application somewhere" is too vague.  Configure a Tomcat instance in Eclipse so that Eclipse uses it.

Comment: "somewhere": sorry for the confusion
I wanted to say:
  - I configured a Tomcat instance in Eclipse
  - the directories used by Eclipse and/or Tomcat are managed by Eclipse and/or Tomcat: I don't fix them
--> the app is deployed in the right directory automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which work for the moment.

In the pom.xml of myLibrary, I had this:

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <revision>${revision}</revision>
[...]
    </properties>
```

The solution was to replace the variable ${revision} with a hardcoded value:

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <revision>1.0</revision>
[...]
    </properties>
```

And now it seems it works.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very recurrent when Eclipse does not add the Java dependencies (libs) to the "assembly" automatically. With Maven, I solve this by using this Eclipse plugin. I believe what you need is just the part that activates version 2.0 : `<wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>`, but I am sending you a more complete configuration to test :

```
<!-- Eclipse project -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
        <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        <manifest>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifest>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```